# Laravel Mail Message Components Prefix

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-mail

I'm trying to customize my email temapltes for laravel. So I published the notifcations and mail vendors.

In the `resources/views/vendor/notifications/email.blade.php` file the framework calls components like this

```
@component('mail::button')
```

For what stands the `mail::` prefix?

I've tryed to write my own component locatete under `resources/views/vendor/mail/mycomponent.blade.php`. So I also call it like the default components.

```
@component('mail::mycomponent')
```

It does not work. Here the error:

```
View [mycomponent] not found. (View: /resources/views/vendor/notifications/email.blade.php)
```

So my question is where the prefix `mail::` points? Can I use it for my own components?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When you do `php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-mail` larvel creates 2 directories inside `resources/views/vendor/mail` called `html` and `markdown`.

You need to have your component in there to make sure it's accessible inside email template.

If you want to create a component, you need to create 2 files : 
`resources/views/vendor/mail/html/mycomponent.blade.php` and `resources/views/vendor/mail/markdown/mycomponent.blade.php`

Markdown will have the data and slots whereas the html one will have actual html structure to render.

The `mail::` prefix is Laravel's way to look for mail components, its not really a folder path in  blade like we do `layouts.default` etc.

See [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/mail#customizing-the-components) for more details.

Comment: I created a new component in both places but still when I send email its shows Facade/Ignition/Exceptions/ViewException with message 'View [coupon] not found